# Java socket connection timed out, works on local

Tags: java, sockets

The code in question is this:

```
class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(4001);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            // streams, buffer, strings, main loop and socket closing; all works fine
        }catch(Exception e) {/*handle*/}
    }
}

class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("24.135.22.219"), 4001); // << Connection fails here.
            // streams, buffer, strings, main loop and socket closing; all works fine
        }catch(Exception e) {/*handle*/}
    }
}
```

It all works fine on local, when `"serverIP"` is replaced with `InetAddress.getByName(null)`. However, when it's replaced with my IP address, the connection isn't made (even though I disable the Windows Firewall) and I get a `Connection timed out` error.

Files for testing are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/398j8f2exxrxtjb/AADAqRi01MZAKrMaRPkebeLQa?dl=0).

Comment: Is the server having hostname as "serverIP" `ping`able? Are the packets transmitted and received?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Yes, I've just tried it in cmd.

Comment: If you're passing "1.2.3.4" IP, that constructor takes a hostname. You need to create an InetAddress to use the IP-address constructor.

Comment: @StefanStanković - Could you include the code as to how you're pinging the server(using IP or hostname)? What is the name and IP of your server?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Code? I just pinged it with cmd, using `ping <IP>` command to see of it's reachable.

Comment: @user1676075 And how do I do that?

Comment: Javadoc, java.net.InetAddress. Pass that instead of a string (the other Socket constructor, can also get there from the Socket page).

Comment: @StefanStanković - I asked you bit about *"What is the name and IP of your server"*?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful It's 24.135.22.219, now yall now where I am. :D

Comment: @user1676075 I've already done `InetAddress.getByName("24.135.22.219")`, but to no effect. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind your `ServerSocket` to the same address as you are trying to connect to:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket();
ss.bind(new InetSocketAddress("<serverIp>", 4001));
Socket s = ss.accept();
```

Comment: um, because at the moment your ServerSocket isn't bound to the external IP address, it's  only bound to localhost which is why you can't connect to it.

Comment: `Cannot assign requested address: JVM_Bind` is all i get.

Comment: That implies that you have something else on your machine running on that address / port. Is anything currently running on that port on your machine?

Comment: Well, shouldn't constructor `ServerSocket(4001)` fail as well, then? It doesn't, to be clear,

Comment: No, because 127.0.0.1:4001 is not the same as 10.11.12.13:4001 (assuming 10.11.12.13 is the public IP address on your machine). `ServerSocket(4001)` is binding to 127.0.0.1:4001

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101003/discussion-between-stefan-stankovic-and-mikea).